# Multiplication in character class in R

Tags: r, vector, character, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

Let have the vector `x=c("x1","x2","x3")`.

Is there any way after the multiplication `x%*%x`to get an output like the following:

```
"x1x1+x2x2+x3x3"
```

or

```
"x1x1"+"x2x2"+"x3x3".
```

My main problem is how to make the multiplication of two vectors of character class. I want also to apply this in a multiplication between two matrices of character class.

Note that I do not want to put any values in `x1`, `x2`, `x3`.

Comment: Is this what you want? `paste0(x, x, collapse="+")`

Comment: Is that a different question? I don't understand.

Comment: @MrFlick no, it is the same! I make a correction, sorry. How the output of `"x1x1+x1x2+x1x3"` to become an output of `"x1^2+x1x2+x1x3"`. To be more specific, when I have a multiplication of two same elements I want an output like `"x1^2"` but not `"x1x1"`.

Comment: i tend to think this is a symbolic computation. check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/symbolic-computation-in-r) for help